# QTCompass - Изменение азимута при кручении вокруг продольной оси

Tags: android, qt, математика, qml

Почему происходит изменение азимута при кручении вокруг оси Y(roll) примерно на +-30' ? Азимут ведь отсчитывается от этой оси? Для подсчета используется QTCompass. Вообще можно как-нибудь компенсировать эту погрешность? Мне необходимо, чтобы все фотографии были сделаны в одной плоскости с допустим отклонением при горизонтальной или вертикальной сьемке.

Answer (score 1):

`roll` это угол относительно горизонтальной оси в направлении движении самолета, кручение вокруг неё - это наклон крыльев (для смартфона аналогично при назначении главной оси)

А азимут - это положение этой проекции этой самой оси  на горизонтальную плоскость относительно мировой системы координат. Если ноль `yaw`  привязан к Земле, то `yaw` даёт азимут при нулевых `pitch` и `roll`. А в общем случае азимут, если не ошибаюсь, выглядит как (однако у меня это были сырые сигналы с инклинометров):

```
az = arctan2(yaw, sqrt(pitch^2 + roll^2))
```

Comment: Есть литература на эту тему?

Comment: @maestrо Наверное, есть, но достаточно много страничек с объяснениями и картинками